# How to get a value of a close in the future?

Tags: pine-script

```
The Chikou Span, also known as the lagging span, is represented by a green line. It is formed by taking the current price and shifting it back 26 periods to the left.
```

So how do I get the value of the close that appeared 26 periods in the future (if that exists)?

Answer (score 1):

The close that is shifted 26 periods to the past/left is the current close. It's just shifted visually.

It's the same as using the `offset` argument of the `plot()`.

```
plot(close, offset=-26)
```

Comment: I understand however I want to do some calculations with it. So if the current price is above or below the lagging span. But at the time of the bar I don't have the value, that's the problem.

Comment: Every bar there is a value for the lagging span, check the Data Window.

Comment: Nvm, I see what you mean.

Comment: Lagging span is actually just the close if you look at the code. You can do your calculations with it now: `lagging_span = close`

Comment: Your code was correct. However it's only visually. So if you look at the current close and the lagging span they should be different. Because the lagging span is the close of the candle 26 bars ahead (and not 26 bars in the past which can be retrieved with close[26])